# Generating function of sequence related to binary expression of integer as follows

Tags: generating-functions, integer-partitions

For any $n \in \Bbb N$, let $O(n)$ be $1$ if the binary expression of $n$ contains even number of ones; and $-1$ if the binary expression of $n$ contains odd number of ones, and $Z(n)$ be $1$ if the binary expression of $n$ contains even number of zeros; and $-1$ if the binary expression of $n$ contains odd number of zeros. For example, $O(5)=1$ and $Z(5)=-1$, since $5=101$ in binary.

I want to show that
$$\sum_{n = 0}^\infty O(n)x^n = \prod_{n = 0}^\infty \left(1-x^{2^n}\right). \qquad (1)$$
I have a guess that
$$\prod_{n = 0}^{k} \left(1-x^{2^n}\right) = \sum_{n = 0}^{2^{k+1}-1} O(n)x^n, \qquad (2)$$
for small value of $k$. My question is, can I show $(1)$ by showing $(2)$ using induction on $k$?
Or, any ideas to show it carefully?

My second question is, how to find generating function of $Z(n)$ and $Z(n)O(n)$, i.e.,
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty Z(n)x^n = \ldots$$
and
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty Z(n)O(n)x^n = \ldots?$$

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: You may find something useful at https://oeis.org/A000069 and/or https://oeis.org/A001969

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thanks for find them all. But, I still didn't get it, especially, the generating function.

Comment: If you look at $a(n)=(1/2)(Z(n)+1)$ you get $a(n)=1$ if $n$ is evil, $a(n)=0$ if $n$ is odious. $a(n)$ is tabulated at https://oeis.org/A010059 and there is a generating function for it there. Then from $Z(n)=2a(n)-1$ you can get a generating function for $Z(n)$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thanks for the hints. I appreciate it. Now, what about my first question? Is it true?

Comment: (1) is trivially true. Every non-negative integer $r$ has a unique representation as a sum of distinct powers of two, $r=2^{a_1}+2^{a_2}+\cdots+2^{a_t}$, so the coefficient of $2^r$ when you multiply out the right side of (1) is $(-1)^t$, which is $O(r)$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Can I show (1) by using (2)?

Comment: It's the same proof.

Comment: @GerryMyerson It means yes? Ok, thanks a lot, Sir!